# Spring putting dynamically generated values into placeholders

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration, mqtt

I am new to Spring. I now understand how to use placeholders to read values from a properties file:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="location" value="classpath:properties.txt"/>
</bean>

<int-mqtt:outbound-channel-adapter id="mqtt-publish"
        client-id="${clientID}"
        client-factory="clientFactory"
        auto-startup="true"
        url="${url}"
        default-qos="${qos}"
        default-retained="${retain}"
        default-topic="${topic}" />
```

Everything works fine with the code above... But... Is it possible for instance to replace the clientID by something generated at runtime (or from user input) instead of statically reading it from a properties file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By runtime, do you mean dynamically for each message?

In that case, no, because the clientId is used while establishing the connection, which is done once (or when the connection to the server is lost).

If you mean to provide a dynamic value programmatically when the application context initializes, then, yes, the [Spring Expression Language](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) is the solution.

For example, `#{myBean.myProperty}` will call the `getMyProperty()` method on a bean `myBean` and `#{myBean.someMethod()}` will invoke `someMethod()`.

Also see the [dynamic-ftp](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp) sample, which uses placeholders at runtime by creating a new outbound adapter on demand using property placeholders, in a child application context.